# AAM original site will not loaded

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping

I have started a SharePoint 2013 site, I only have the Central Administration and the site named after the server (we will call this one `spSrvr`). I wanted people to be able to use the company name instead of using the server name so, instead of `http://spSrvr` I wanted them to use `//spFishco`.

I changed the IIS binding, added spFishco to DNS, and did the AAM in central admin (I added the `//spFishco` to Intranet because I still want to use spsrvr too. Both worked (pretty sure I checked both), but this morning I decided to change `//spFishco` to the default and place `//spSrvr` in the intranet. I can still use `//spFishco`, but I get an error when trying to connect when using `//spSrvr`. Is there a reason? Any ideas?

Comment: what error you are getting? did you change the IIS bindings as well?

Comment: Weird, it worked Wednesday, then Thursday it didn't, but today it was working. Which it should, everything should be set up right. Thanks for our help though. I'm just going to keep checking up on it.

Comment: this question doesnt make any value to the forum as it has no proper explanation and answer. Pls delete the question if you couldnt find anything  else provide proper notes on analysis..